# R counting count subsets within df-increasing performance

Tags: r, performance

I'm currently working with a data set that looks something like this

```
Host   V1   V2   V3   V4
H1     1    1    1    1
H1     1    1    1    0
H2     1    1    0    0
H2     1    0    0    0
H3     0    0    0    0
H3     1    1    1    1
```

Where the top line is simply a header. The end goal is to be able to count the number of 1s in each column, with each category of Host. This would look something like this

```
Host   V1   V2   V3   V4
H1     2    2    2    1
H2     2    1    0    0
H3     1    1    1    1
```

Currently I'm using the following code

```
ddply(data,.(data[,1]),numcolwise(sum))
```

This has been giving me the right output, which has been great and all, until I needed to run this operation thousands upon thousands of times, for many different generated datasets. Typically, this takes hours if not days, when ideally this could be reduced to several minutes. When I analyzed my overall code with Rprof, it identified the ddply function as the taking the vast majority of the time. I'd like to speed this process up significantly, but I don't know a more efficient way of condensing these data sets.

Answer (score 2):

The data.table package seems to be much faster:

```
Arrgh!> library(data.table)
Arrgh!> read.table(t="Host   V1   V2   V3   V4
+ H1     1    1    1    1
+ H1     1    1    1    0
+ H2     1    1    0    0
+ H2     1    0    0    0
+ H3     1    1    1    1", h=T)->df
Arrgh!> dt<-data.table(df)
Arrgh!> dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Host]
   Host V1 V2 V3 V4
1:   H1  2  2  2  1
2:   H2  2  1  0  0
3:   H3  1  1  1  1
```

For example:

```
Arrgh!> H <- c("H1","H2","H3")
Arrgh!> V <- c(0,1)
Arrgh!> df <- data.frame(Host=sample(H, 1000, r=T), V1=sample(V,1000,r=T), V2=sample(V,1000,r=T), V3=sample(V,1000,r=T), V4=sample(V,1000,r=T))
Arrgh!> dt <- data.table(df)
Arrgh!> library(microbenchmark)

Arrgh!> microbenchmark(dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Host])
Unit: milliseconds
                              expr   min   lq  mean median    uq   max neval
 dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Host] 1.515 1.56 1.655  1.581 1.627 4.288   100

Arrgh!> microbenchmark(ddply(df,.(df[,1]),numcolwise(sum)))
Unit: milliseconds
                                   expr   min    lq  mean median    uq   max neval
 ddply(df, .(df[, 1]), numcolwise(sum)) 4.097 4.173 4.458  4.236 4.343 9.958   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
  library(dplyr)
  df1 %>% 
    group_by(Host) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum))
  #   Host V1 V2 V3 V4
  #1   H1  2  2  2  1
  #2   H2  2  1  0  0
  #3   H3  1  1  1  1
```

Or `aggregate` from `base R`

```
 aggregate(.~Host, df1, FUN=sum)
 #   Host V1 V2 V3 V4
 #1   H1  2  2  2  1
 #2   H2  2  1  0  0
 #3   H3  1  1  1  1
```

Or using `rowsum`

```
rowsum(df1[-1], group = df1$Host)
#    V1 V2 V3 V4
#H1  2  2  2  1
#H2  2  1  0  0
#H3  1  1  1  1
```